# C++ boost returns HTML instead JSON

Tags: c++, json, boost-asio

**Hi, there!**
I am new to network programming and the BOOST library. I am trying to get information about exchange rates through the REST API https://fcsapi.com/
However, instead of JSON, I get the HTML markup of the page. How do I get the JSON? What am I doing wrong?
I have been busy all day today looking for an answer to this question on *google.com*. Guide me on the right path, please.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

boost::asio::io_service service;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;

std::string getCurrencyForex()
{
    std::string site = "fcsapi.com";
    std::string arg = "https://fcsapi.com/api-v3/forex/latest?symbol=all_forex&access_key=FatQMAUbzGqpOmdltVuMNA";

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);

    boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(site, "80"));
    http::request<http::string_body> req(http::verb::get, arg, 11);

    req.set(http::field::host, site);
    req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

    http::write(socket, req);

    std::string response;

    {
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
        http::read(socket, buffer, res);
        response = boost::beast::buffers_to_string(res.body().data());
    }

    socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
    return response;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getCurrencyForex() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwDFq.png)

Comment: You should hide your access token

Comment: what if you use `arg = "/api-v3/forex/latest?symbol=all_forex&access_key=[your-access-key]";`?

Comment: Consider using [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/).

Comment: That's a 404 page-not-found error.  Are you using the correct URL?

Comment: @frachop Why?  Boost.Asio and Boost.Beast are highly tested and respected libraries.  The problem is the OP's code, not the libraries.

Comment: @Ruzihm, thank you. You resolved my issue, but I cant`t mark your comment as resolve.

Comment: @cmannett85 : you absolutely right, boost.beast is amazing and i use it a lot. But i thought that here this was a kind of "continue 100" problem and libcurl deals transparently with those things. Furthermore, libcurl is imho easier to use.

Comment: @CupaState Glad I could help. I wrote it down below as an answer.

Comment: @CupaState Consider accepting my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of the constructor of `boost::request<http::string_body>` should be only the path and the query string. So, it will work if you use:

`std::string arg = /api-v3/forex/latest?symbol=all_forex&access_key=[your-access-key]";`